# mongodb multiple documents insert or update by unique key

Tags: mongodb

I would like to get a list of items from an external resource periodically and save them into a collection.

There are several possible solutions but they are not optimal, for example:

1. Delete the entire collection and save the new list of items
2. Get all items from the collection using "find({})" and use it to filter out existing items and save those that do not exist.

But a better solution will be to set a unique key and just do kind of "update or insert". 
Right now on saving items the unique key already exists I will get an error
is there a way to do it at all?

**upsert won't do the work since it's updating all items with the same value so it's actually good for a single document only

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help others to answer your question, please provide some sample data and code of you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert or update many documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244739/insert-or-update-many-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you can achieve what you want simply by using the "normal" [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#db-collection-insertmany) with the `ordered` option set to `false`. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#insert-several-document-specifying-an-id-field) states that

> Note that one document was inserted: The first document of _id: 13
>   will insert successfully, but the second insert will fail. This will
>   also stop additional documents left in the queue from being inserted.
>   **With ordered to false, the insert operation would continue with any
>   remaining documents.**

So you will get "duplicate key" exceptions which, however, you can simply ignore in your case.